# Read in Single Quote using getline()

Tags: c++, getline

I'm doing UVa Problem 10082 and I'm trying to read in some sample input to test my solution. However, when I read in the text `'''CCC` it outputs `;;XXX`. Note that there are only 2 semi-colons, when there should be 3 since there are 3 single quotes in the input. Why is getline() ignoring the first single quote?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char mapToWertyu(char c)
{
    char newC = c;
    char wertyu[] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','-','=',
                     'Q','W','E','R','T','Y','U','I','O','P','[',']','\\',
                     'A','S','D','F','G','H','J','K','L',';','\'',
                     'Z','X','C','V','B','N','M',',','.','/'};
    char qwerty[] = {'~','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','-','=',
                     'Q','W','E','R','T','Y','U','I','O','P','[',']','\\',
                     'A','S','D','F','G','H','J','K','L',';','\'',
                     'Z','X','C','V','B','N','M',',','.','/'};
    if(c=='A' || c=='Q' || c=='Z')
        return c;

    for(int i = 0; i < 47; ++i)
    {
        if(wertyu[i]==c)
        {
            newC = qwerty[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return newC;
}

int main()
{
    string input;
    while(cin.peek()!=-1)
    {
        getline(cin,input);
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i)
        {
            if(input[i]!='\\')
                cout << mapToWertyu(input[i]);
        }
        cin.ignore(1,'\n');
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I cut and pasted your code into VS2013 and ran it.  On that system '''CCC produces ;;;XXX

Comment: @Dweeberly Just a guess, but the input he's having problems with is probably not the first line.  He ignores the first character of every line but the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you tell it to.  What do you thing `std::cin.ignore( 1,
'\n' )` should do, if not ignore a character.  `std::getline`
extracts the `'\n'` character, even if it doesn't put it into
the string.

For the rest, you're not doing the input right.  For starters, `std::cin.peek()` will return an integer in the
range `[0...UCHAR_MAX]` or `EOF`.  `EOF` is often defined to be
`-1`, but this is certainly not guaranteed.  But more generally:
why not use the usual idiom:

```
while ( std::getline( std::cin, input ) ) {
    //  ...
}
```

You also construct the arrays in `mapToWertyu` each time you
call it.  That is definitly not what you want to do.  You could
use just one static array, indexed directly by the character,
bug this does make the program dependent on the encoding.  To
use two arrays, however:

```
static char const wertyu[] = { ... };
static char const qwerty[] = { ... };
char const* pos = std::find( std::begin( wertyu ), std::end( wertyu ), c );
return pos == std::end( wertyu )
    ? c
    : qwerty[ pos - std::begin( wertyu ) ];
```

Solves the problem in a much simpler manner.  (And there's no
need to special case `'A'`, `'Q'` and `'Z'`.  If you don't want
to transcode them, just don't put them in the table.)

Or...

```
struct Map
{
    char from;
    char to;
};
static Map const map[] =
{
    { '1', '~' },
    { '2', '1' },
    //  ...
};
Map const* pos = std::find_if( std::begin( map ), std::end( map ),
                    []( char ch ) { return c == ch; } );
return pos == std::end( map )
    ? c
    : pos->to;
```

This has the advantage of making the exact mapping visible.

Or if you're 100% sure you'll never have to worry about threads:

```
struct Map
{
    char from;
    char to;
};
static Map map[] =
{
    { '1', '~' },
    { '2', '1' },
    //  ...
    {  0,   0  }
};
Map* sentinal = std::end( map ) - 1;
sentinal->to = sentinal->from = c;
Map const* pos = std::find_if( std::begin( map ), std::end( map ),
                    []( Map const& entry ) { return c == entry.from; } );
return pos->to;
```

By inserting the sentinal, you can be sure that the entry will
be found.

Or you could sort the map, and use `std::lower_bound`.

Also, why do you call the function `mapToWertyu`, when it maps
to querty?

Comment: Addressing the problem at hand, that was a really silly mistake as I'd even said to myself "remember to remove the `cin.ignore()`".
For the rest of the answer, not that it's any excuse, but I'd just been throwing this code together quickly for an answer. I'm glad you wrote this anyway, as I'm somewhat unfamiliar with everything C++ has to offer, and you've suggested far better ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Actually just remembered I was originally going to use a Map, but I thought it'd be quicker to just throw the two arrays together.

Comment: @rar I used lambdas (which is C++11) for convenient.  In pre-C++11, you'd have to move the code in the lambdas out into a separate functional object.  (I do this often enough that I've a template `StaticMap` which defined the functional objects for me.)